# Using idFTP before creating a form

Tags: delphi, ftp

So i'm tying to use a idFTP component before any form is created.
I'm calling a function that needs to check for a file on an ftp server so I need to create it.

Here's the function:

```
function restoreBackup(online: Boolean = TRUE): Boolean;  //restores backup from server              if possible, if not from disk
var
FTP: TidFTP;
begin
if online then
begin
FTP:=FTP.Create();
FTP.Host:=getConfig('ftphost');
FTP.Username:=getConfig('ftpuser');
FTP.Port:=StrToInt(getConfig('ftpport'));
FTP.Password:=getConfig('ftppass');
try
FTP.Connect;
FTP.ChangeDir(getConfig('ftpbkpdir'));
if FTP.Size('masterlist.dat')<>-1 then
    begin
    FTP.Get('masterlist.dat', getConfig('masterlistpath'));
    end;
        except
        MessageDlg('Impossible de se connecter au serveur, la sauvegarde sera restaurée à partir du disque.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
        end;
end;

//restore from disk

FTP.Free;
end;
```

It is called from the project's source:

```
var
Sel: Integer;
begin
Application.Initialize;
global.initGlobal;
if not global.verifyPaths then   //verify if all paths are good
begin
Sel:=MessageDlg('Un des chemins d''accès est erroné. L''application peut restaurer la     dernière sauvegarde mais il se peut que certaines informations soient perdues. Voulez-vous continuer?',
mtError, [mbYes,mbNo], 0);
if Sel=6 then  //6 is mrYes
begin
io.restoreBackup(); //// It gets called here.
end else
  begin
  Application.Terminate;
  end;
end else
begin
//Create Forms
Application.Run;
end;
end.
```

When the function is called, I get an access violation. I'm pretty sure I'm not creating it properly but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: the line `FTP:=FTP.Create();` should be `FTP:=TidFTP.Create(nil);`. Also remember protect the resources using a `try finally` block.

Comment: Well thank you very much! You may post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `FTP:=FTP.Create();` should be `FTP:=TidFTP.Create(nil);`. Also remember protect the resources using a try finally block.

Like this

```
var
  FTP: TidFTP;
begin
if online then
begin
  FTP:=TidFTP.Create(nil);
  try
  FTP.Host:=getConfig('ftphost');
  FTP.Username:=getConfig('ftpuser');
  FTP.Port:=StrToInt(getConfig('ftpport'));
  FTP.Password:=getConfig('ftppass');
   try
    FTP.Connect;
    FTP.ChangeDir(getConfig('ftpbkpdir'));
    if FTP.Size('masterlist.dat')<>-1 then
      FTP.Get('masterlist.dat', getConfig('masterlistpath'));
   except
    MessageDlg('Impossible de se connecter au serveur, la sauvegarde sera restaurée à partir du disque.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
   end;

  finally
    FTP.Free;
   end;
end;
```